# Write to a file from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to run a process which I will put into a bash script (once I figure it out properly). I'm trying to write to text file:

```
martyn@localhost:/var/www$ sudo cat << EOF > /var/git/myproject.git/hooks/post-update
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "**** Pulling changes into Live [Hub's post-update hook]"
echo

cd /var/www/myproject || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master

exec git-update-server-info
EOF
```

..but give the following error:

```
-bash: /var/git/myproject.git/hooks/post-update: Permission denied
```

I thought by putting `sudo` I would have permission here, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File redirections happen in the shell before sudo is called.  There's a common idiom in bash to accomplish what you're trying to do like this:

```
sudo tee /var/git/myproject.git/hooks/post-update <<EOF >/dev/null
```

This way tee (under sudo) writes to the output file, and you throw away the secondary output stream from tee.

Comment: Are you sure tee is a bash idiom? It's `/usr/bin/tee` here.

Comment: Well, I meant a common idiom in shell, but yes, tee is external.

Answer (score 0):

Another efficient way is:

```
sudo bash -c 'exec cat > /var/git/myproject.git/hooks/post-update' << EOF
...
EOF
```

Note: Some shells actually supports `-c` like the way `bash` does so you could use it on them as well.